# Error - Globalthrowablemapper requested keymanager not found

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have been trying to add WSO2-IS as a keymanager in WSO2-APIM. I was added and when toggle button ON to enable WSO2-IS. But when refresh again, it auotmatically toggle button OFF again.When I see the log, its said Error - Globalthrowablemapper requested keymanager not found.
Can someone help me out?

I try keymanager configuration and restart Identity server.